# Doing action based on input from options menu

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

This is my first time writing plugin. I have managed to get options menu with the html form:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'menu');
function menu(){
    add_options_page("poster","poster",'manage_options',"poster",'option_page_html');
}
function option_page_html(){
    ?>
    <div>
        <form action="wp-content/plugins/poster/post-video.php" method="post">
            <p><h3>Paste video url</h3></p>
            <input type="text" size="100" name="url" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I want to make a script which `insert_post` from the url I paste in the `input` field. It's not autoblogger, I just want to make it easier to embed some related videos which I now do manually.
The problem is in the `form action="wp-content/plugins/poster/post-video.php"` part. It seems that wordpress search for that file only in `wp-admin` folder so it becomes `http://example.com/wp-admin/wp-content/plugins/poster/post-video.php` when I try to post, with error 404.

I have tried `form action="<?php echo __DIR__."/post-video.php"?>"`, but when I post it goes to `http://example.com/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/poster/post-video.php"`

How to get the right path for the `post-video.php` script inside plugin folder?
Or is there some other method, built-in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post to the same URL and catch the submit ex:

```
function option_page_html(){
    if (isset($_POST['plugin_action']) && $_POST['plugin_action'] == 'post_url'){
        include_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'post-video.php');
    }
    ?>
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><h3>Paste video url</h3></p>
            <input type="text" size="100" name="url" /><br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="plugin_action" value="post_url">
            <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

**note** : this is an example and you should make sure you sanitize and validate the value and probably use [**`nonce`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) for better security